# How to run parallel execution, if we have 4 api url which have 4 events in loadrunner?

Tags: loadrunner

Could you please let me know how to do parallel mode of execution in loadrunner for 4 api urls for 4 events in loadrunner??

Needed parallel execution in loadrunner

Answer (score 0):

Please define parallel execution in this context

- These APIs are all a part of a single business flow execution, do not depend upon each other and I need to reproduce the behavior of a browser that can open six threads at once for a given host
- These four API calls are running as a part of four independent virtual users and I need to synchronize the behavior of these four users to ensure that all four API calls are submitted nearly simultaneously to address a specific engineering requirement associated with parallel thread execution for these four API calls.
- I simply need to run four virtual users, each with an API call.  Simultaneity is not called for (all calls at the exact same instant), but execution within the same concurrent window is.

Related: Have you been through product training for LoadRunner and do you have a mentor assigned to assist in your efforts?  Your answer to this question helps guide the types of answers and assistance required for your success.